# Selectively disable Parenthetical Currency Conversion

Tags: multi-currency, currency

I'm trying to find a way to disable the 'Parenthetical Currency Conversion' only for a specific object.

Currently, we have one custom object where the business requires a different exchange rate system than the ECB one referenced by Salesforce. To prevent any confusion, I would like to hide/disable the converted amount that's automatically displayed for the currency fields on that object, but the only option I seem to find is to disable the currency conversion for the entire org, which is not acceptable as other objects do still need this conversion.

Is there some way to make such an exception on this custom object?

Answer (score 0):

If your calculated currency field is a required field then you can hide it but the problem you will not be able to create a new record for that particular object. If the field you are trying to hide is not required field then you remove the field from the page layout.